# Question for an ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is an ODE
$$u'=(u-u_L)(u-u_R)$$
$u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R};\ \ u=u(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}u(x)=u_R;\ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}u(x)=u_L $ and $u_L>u_R, u'(\pm\infty)=0$

To solve this;
I change the ode as
$$\frac{du}{(u-u_L)(u-u_R)}=dx$$
$$\frac{1}{u_L-u_R}\int\frac{1}{u-u_L}-\frac{1}{u-u_R}du=\int dx$$
$$\frac{1}{u_L-u_R}\log\Big{|}\frac{u-u_L}{u-u_R}\Big{|}=x+c$$

here I wonder we can convince that $u_L>u(x)>u_R,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$?
If we accept this, we can change above
$$\frac{1}{u_L-u_R}\log\frac{u_L-u}{u-u_R}=x+c$$
and we can easily solve it.
I wonder in this condition how can we verify $u_L>u>u_R$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assume that. Because of the limit conditions, there has to be some intermediary point $x_0$ with $u(x_0)\in(u_R,u_L)$. By the general principles of one-dimensional autonomous ODE, no solution can cross the equilibrium positions $u_L,u_R$, due to the uniqueness of solutions of locally Lipschitz ODE. Thus the whole solution has to be contained inside that interval.

You could also check that any solution outside the interval $[u_R,u_L]$ has a pole at finite time, as for sufficiently large $|u|$, the equation behaves like the well-known example $u'=u^2$. Thus there will be only one side of the domain at infinity.

Comment: Actually I know the fact the uniquness of the solution of the locally lipschitz ode, But, I don't know how we can explain the limit condition imply the existence of intermediary point . And I want to study the principles of one dimensional autonomous ode, do you have any source about this?

Comment: No, just common-sense observations about constant solutions, uniqueness, signs of derivatives and monotonicity. But this should be explained in any decent ODE book.